Не создаться файл PDF (android studeo)
У меня есть код в Android studeo который должен записывать введённый текст в pdf файл, но почему-то запись в pdf файл не работает. Можете помочь с этой проблемой
public void CreatePDF(View view) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument IP31 = new PdfDocument();
    PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageinfo =
            new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 100, 1).create();
    PdfDocument.Page bestPage = IP31.startPage(myPageinfo);
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    String bestString = MyText.getText().toString();
    int x = 20, y = 40;
    bestPage.getCanvas().drawText(bestString, x, y, myPaint);
    IP31.finishPage(bestPage);
    String bestPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File bestFile = new File(bestPath, "my_pdf_file.pdf");
    IP31.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(bestFile));
    IP31.close();
}


"запись в pdf файл не работает" - как именно не работает? Пустой файл, битый, вообще не создает файл?

Вообще не создаёт PDF файл

Пишите все уточнения в вопрос пожалуйста, кнопка "править"
